# jQuery replace text of element

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am trying to replace a div in a jQuery dropdown box. The value to be replaced is the "header" of the dropdown box that says "Pick alternative:" when nothing is picked. Then when the user chooses an alternative from the dropdown, that alternative gets highlighted and also replaces "Pick alternative:" so that the user can see what they chose when closing the dropdown.

How would I do this?

The HTML:

```
    <div class="step_content">
        <div class="vertical_text">Choose alternative</div>
        <div class="vertical_content dropdown_fade">
            <div class="menu_corner top_left_vertical"></div>
            <div class="menu_corner top_right_vertical"></div>                                                                      
            <div class="button_slide" rel="slide1">Pick alternative:</div>
            <div class="content_slide slide1">
                <input id="Button19" class="button_vertical damage_button" type="button" value="Alternative 1" size="10px" />
                <input id="Button20" class="button_vertical damage_button" type="button" value="Alternative 2" />  
                                                               
            </div>                                            
            <div class="menu_corner bottom_left_vertical"></div>
            <div class="menu_corner bottom_right_vertical"></div>                   
        </div>                
    </div>
```

I have the following lines of JavaScript. I'm not sure how to continue doing this.

```
$(function () {
        $('.damage_button').click(function () {
            $('.button_slide').replaceWith("<div class='some_class' >" + $(this) + "</div>");
        });
});
```

I get it to replace what I want to be replaced but it just shows "[Object object]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
        $('.damage_button').click(function () {
            $('.button_slide').replaceWith("<div class='some_class' >" + $(this).val() + "</div>");
        });
});
```

Use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for `INPUT` elements (a button is an `INPUT` element), and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for a non-`INPUT` elements.

The reason you get `[Object object]` is because when you simply do `$(this)` and concatenate it to a string, you are calling the jQuery object's `toString()` which doesn't return what you want. You want the actual text of the button, which you get by using `val()`.

Comment: @Nick why would it be wrong? Doesn't it get the clicked button's text?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the clicked `<input>` element's value, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.damage_button').click(function () {
    $('.button_slide').replaceWith("<div class='some_class' >" + $(this).val() + "</div>");
  });
});
```

In this case `this` refers to the `<input>` you want, but `$(this)` is a jQuery object..which gives a `.toString()` of `[Object object]`, you want [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value.